# do I need to have active storage setup for my seed data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activestorage

I am working on a final project using ruby/rails and active record on the backend and react on the frontend. Still at the beginning and am making some seed data for me to be able to work with.

I was also going to seed a singular user but I later plan to implement active storage into my project for the user profile picture. Should I take this into account for the user I am seeding right now and already have active storage setup or can I worry about that later down the line?

Still haven't taken much time to learn about it right now just want to get the skeleton of the project going and was planning to dive into learning about it later.

Here's the user migration I already created:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :photo
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the user I was planning to seed without having setup active storage yet

```
user = User.create([
  {
    username: "test", 
    password: "test",
    photo: "https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/peoples-avatars/no-profile-picture-icon.png"
   }
])
```

Comment: Do you need to have ActiveStorage setup to use it to store files? Yes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

For **skeleton** you don't need to configure the active storage.
Active storage just converting attachment files by address to database.

But that approach is wrong, my advise - just use https://shrinerb.com/

They easier than active storage

Comment: its a project requirement to use Active Storage or else I'd use shrine

Answer (score -1):

[ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) is a Rails component designed to work with `Rails` applications to upload files.

In your example you are simply adding a string (photo url) as an attribute of a model. If you want to upload a photo file you have to add
`has_one_attached :photo` to `User` model and remove `t.string :photo` from migration.

And a fix to your seed is like this:

```
user = User.create(username: 'test', password: 'test', photo: 'https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/peoples-avatars/no-profile-picture-icon.png')
```

If you want to seed an attachment:

```
user = User.new(username: 'test', password: 'test')
user.photo.attach(io: File.open(Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'photos', 'no-profile-picture-icon.png')), filename: 'photo1', content_type: 'image/png')
user.save
```

or

```
user = User.new(username: 'test', password: 'test')
    
photo = URI.parse("https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/peoples-avatars/no-profile-picture-icon.png").open
user.photo.attach(io: photo, filename: "no-profile-picture-icon.png")
user.save
```